# R ggplot2: How to connect points with arrows in Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, coordinates

I am interested in learning how to connect points with the `arrow()` function on a Cartesian plane using the [ggplot2](/questions/tagged/ggplot2) package.

Data:

```
Coord = data.frame(x=c(2,-5,7),y=c(4,12,-78))
ggplot()+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-136,136), ylim = c(-6,210))
```

I tried using `geom_segment`, but I am not sure how to proceed.

I wanted to learn how to connect one point to many points ?

I intend to use this method to make pass maps for soccer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, you need to create variables `xend` and `yend` in your data frame that represent the ends of the lines.

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(2,-5,7),y=c(4,12,-78))
df$xend <- c(df$x[2:nrow(df)], NA)
df$yend <- c(df$y[2:nrow(df)], NA)
df <- df[1:(nrow(df)-1),]
```

Plot with `geom_segment`:

```
ggplot(df)+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-136,136), ylim = c(-6,210))+
 geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

UPDATE: From one point to many points:
Example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=c(2,2,2,2,2),y=c(4,4,4,4,4), xend=c(34,3,12,100,-123), yend=c(18,-5,44,200,178))

ggplot(df)+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-136,136), ylim = c(-6,210))+
     geom_segment(aes(x=x,y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend))
```

Comment: Yeah! Makes sense. And could you even explain for one to many points ?

Comment: I updated my answer but I'm not sure I understood correctly what you mean.